# When mapping over an array to generate React components, array order is not respected

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have an array of image src's (`this.props.images`) which I'm using to render a grid in a project I made using Gatsby. This works as expected when running locally - the images are rendered in the order in which they appear in the array. However, I built and deployed a version to Netlify and am finding the images get rendered in what seems to be a random order, which does not match the order of the original array.

Any ideas what could be causing this behaviour? Here's the code:

```
const Grid = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-auto-rows: minMax(100px, auto);
`

export default class Board extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Grid>
                {this.props.images.map((image, index) => (
                    <Image key={index} src={image}>
                    </Image>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: React Devtools showing React components appearing in correct order with correct props according]

[image: Elements however getting different src values]

Comment: Try to debug from react developer tool, check if this component (Board) receives the array as you expect. So, however it appears there, the array should be that way. There is no other way. You can check the array from react dev tool.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that this is caused because you are using indexes as keys.

You could try two libraries to generate unique id: uuid or uniqid

```
npm install uniqid

import uniqueid from 'uniqid'

<Grid>{list.map((item) => <li key={uniqueid()}>{item}</li>)}</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've made the keys unique now, which seems to generally be better practice - but I don't think that it would have an effect in this case, since I'm not changing the order/adding/removing any components? Anyhow, the problem remains! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like local and Netlify each have different default sorts, so how about giving the function the sort you want?
The below should enforce the order of items from the array.

```
{this.props.images.map((image, index) => (
    <Image key={index} src={image}>
    </Image>)).sort(() => a - b )
  }
</Grid>
```

Comment: `local and Netlify each have different default sorts`. Huh?

Comment: Thanks! Have now realised the React components were actually being generated in the right order as expected, but the value of the src prop is somehow not filtering through correctly (added some more info above)...